# How do I loop through elements and use the index number to present the relative array object properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an array object with some dummy properties, I have have also dynamically created some list items that I would like to attach a click handler to. When a list item is clicked I would like to present the appropriate data inside #container using the template Ive set up. Im assuming I can use the index from the for loop of dynamic list items and some how use this to show the correct object properties? If you could advise me where I have gone wrong with this that would be great, sorry but Ive lost my way a little with this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var data = [

    {
        name: 'kyle',
        age: 23,
        sex: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'james',
        age: 19,
        sex: 'male'
    }, {
        name: 'catrina',
        age: 28,
        sex: 'female'
    }];

    var template = $('#template').html();

    // Links created dynamically
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var link = '<li>Link ' + i + '</li>';
        $('#links').append(link);
    }

    // When li is clicked show related data properties, li[0] = data[0], li[1] = data[1] ...
    $('li', '#links').live('click', function (e) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('#container').append(data.name[i], data.age[i], data.sex[i]);
        });

        $('#container').html(data);
    });

});
```

Code can be found here http://jsbin.com/otirax/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to add a data item to each link when you create it that contains the index.  You can then fetch that index later upon click:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    var link = '<li data-index="' + i + '">Link ' + i + '</li>';
    $('#links').append(link);
}
```

Then, in your click handler, you can retrieve that value:

```
$('li', '#links').live('click', function(e){ 
    // retrieve index
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    // retrieve piece of data for this link
    var thisData = data[index];
    // do whatever you need to with the data for this link here
    // thisData.name
    // thisData.age
    // thisData.sex
});
```

This way of storing and then retrieving the index provides a permanent index value set on each `li` at the time you create it.  If you will never reorder the `li` tags and they are the only objects at that level, you can simplify it a bit by using the [.index() jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) that will calculate the index for a given `li` tag dynamically when needed by just counting how many siblings come before it:

```
// Links created dynamically
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var link = '<li>Link ' + i + '</li>';
    $('#links').append(link);
}

$('li', '#links').live('click', function(e){ 
    // retrieve index
    var index = $(this).index();
    // retrieve piece of data for this link
    var thisData = data[index];
    // do whatever you need to with the data for this link here
});
```

---

FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated and one should use `.on()` for jQuery 1.7+ or `.delegate()` for earlier versions of jQuery.

Your `.live()` code would be this with `.on()`:

```
$('#links').on('click', 'li', function(e){
```

Comment: thanks for this, im having difficulty combining the new index number from the data-attribute with the object to output the properties. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong:            $('#links').on('click', 'li', function(e){ 
    var index = $(this).data('index'); 
    
    $.each(data,function(idx,obj){
      var temp = 
          template.replace(/name/ig, obj[index].name)
                  .replace(/age/ig, obj[index].age)
                  .replace(/sex/ig, obj[index].sex);
      $('#container').html(temp);
    });

Comment: @Styler - assuming you want just one of the items from the `data` array, you do not want to be using `.each()`, you just want to be using `data[index]`.  In the future, you can't really put multi-line code in comments, so it's better to add it to your question and format it as code and then refer to it from a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This part has two errors:

```
 $.each(data, function (index, value) {
     $('#container').append(data.name[i], data.age[i], data.sex[i]);
 });
```

The first one, if you want to access to the data's element via `index` you should have:

```
data[index].name
```

The second one, you don't need that because you already have this array's element in `value`, so:

```
$("#container").append(value.name, value.age, value.sex);
```

However I don't think this is what you want. Even with this fix, your code will add to "#container" ALL the values in `data` – because that what you're doing. You're saying to the browser "when you click to these element, list all of my data values, and add them to #container".

I think what you really want is something like that:

```
$('li', '#links').live('click', function(e){ 
    var index = $(this).index(), value = data[index];
    $("#container").append(value.name, value.age, value.sex);
});
```

Notice that in jQuery you can also add data to an element using `data`: http://api.jquery.com/data/